# Hide Public Properties of Base Class in Derived Class

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance

I was wondering if we could hide `public` properties of `Base Class` in `Derived Class`.

I have following sample problem statement for calculating `Area` of different shapes -

```
abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract float Area();
}

class Circle : Shape
{
    private const float PI = 3.14f;

    public float Radius { get; set; }
    public float Diameter { get { return this.Radius * 2; } }

    public Circle() { }

    public Circle(float radius)
    {
        this.Radius = radius;
    }

    public override float Area()
    {
        return PI * this.Radius * this.Radius;
    }
}

class Triangle : Shape
{
    public float Base { get; set; }
    public float Height { get; set; }

    public Triangle() { }

    public Triangle(float @base, float height)
    {
        this.Base = @base;
        this.Height = height;
    }

    public override float Area()
    {
        return 0.5f * this.Base * this.Height;
    }
}

class Rectangle : Shape
{
    public float Height { get; set; }
    public float Width { get; set; }

    public Rectangle() { }

    public Rectangle(float height, float width)
    {
        this.Height = height;
        this.Width = width;
    }

    public override float Area()
    {
        return Height * Width;
    }
}

class Square : Rectangle
{
    public float _side;

    public float Side
    {
        get { return _side; }
        private set
        {
            _side = value;
            this.Height = value;
            this.Width = value;
        }
    }

    // These properties are no more required
    // so, trying to hide them using new keyword
    private new float Height { get; set; }
    private new float Width { get; set; }

    public Square() : base() { }

    public Square(float side)
        : base(side, side)
    {
        this.Side = side;
    }
}
```

Now interesting part is here that in `Square` class `Height` & `Width` properties are no more required (as it is replaced by `Side` property) to expose to outer wold so I am using `new` keyword to hide them. But it is not working and user now can set `Height` and `Width` -

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Shape s = null;

        // Height & Width properties are still accessible :(
        s = new Square() { Width = 1.5f, Height = 2.5f };

        Console.WriteLine("Area of shape {0}", s.Area());
    }
}
```

Does anyone know in C# is it possible to hide properties of derived class which are not required?

**Important Note:**
One might point out that `Shape -> Rectangle -> Square` is not a suitable design of inheritance. But I would like to keep it that way because I do not want to write "not exact" but similar code again in `Square` class (note: `Square` class makes use of `Area` method of its base class `Rectangle`. In real world, in case of such type of inheritance that method logic may be more complicated)

Comment: Rather than present us with a manufactured example of a design you know to be wrong, why don't you ask us about your *actual* situation?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense what you're trying to do. If you don't what the properties Height and Width in the Square object, then Square should inherit from Shape, not Rectangle.

Comment: @Oded Yep that's true in case of shapes. But it would duplicated the logic of calculating `Area` in both `Rectangle` & `Shape`. By theory everyone knows that [b]`Square` is a `Rectangle`[/b]. Logically we should inherit `Square` from `Rectangle`. We might find such scenario in `real wold examples` other than shapes. Then that common logic would be duplicated. My question is around that.

Comment: There is something called 'protected'

Comment: "everyone knows that [b]Square is a Rectangle[/b]".  I disagree, and I think this is why your model breaks down.  I think a better design would be `Shape -> ConvexPolygon -> RegularConvexPolygon ->Square` and `Shape -> ConvexPolygon -> Rectangle`.  That way, all RegularConvexPolygons can share the [Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon#Area) calculation (all the way out to even Circle, if your language supports calculating limits to infinity).

Answer (score 6):

Any sub-type is still fundamentally capable of being treated an instances of the base-type. You certainly can't hide the members if someone has a variable *typed as the base-type*. The most you can do would be to make them really annoying to use *when using the derived type*, for example:

```
[Obsolete, Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public new float Width { get { return base.Width;} }
```

You could also do something similar with `override`, and possibly even `throw` if the accessors (the `set` in particular) are used inappropriately.

However, it sounds more like you should be changing the inheritance model such that you never *want* to try to remove members.

Answer (score 3):

I still think that `Shape -> Rectangle -> Square` is the source of all problems. Inheritance is not just about code reuse. If you have similar code to compute area, you can **compose** the logic: i.e. externalize the logic of area computation to a separate class, and reuse that in Square and Rectangle.

Coming back to your original question, the fact that you need to hide properties in the base class from the child classes is a big design smell - and the language designers would most definitely not have wanted such a feature.

(You may also want to read about [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))

Comment: As per `Liskov Substitution Principle` if `S is a T` then S must Inherit from T ie, `T(base) -> S(derived)`. In sour case `Square is a Rectangle` then why not `Rectangle (base) -> Square (derived)`?

Comment: "Square is a rectangle" is mathematically correct. But the object modelling on the same lines is unfortunately incorrect. LSP states that a sub-class should be able to replace wherever a base class has been used. A "SetWidth()" which was previously being called on a base class(i.e. Rectangle) cannot be called on a sub-class (i.e. Square), because that will compromise the latter's state.

Comment: @ParagMeshram While squares are rectangles, they aren't the same thing as rectangles.  See [Is a Square a Rectangle?](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SquareRectangle.aspx) and [Circle-Ellipse Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Comment: @ParagMeshram If "Square is a Rectangle", then Square has a Width and Height, and they should be exposed.  Just because you don't *need* Width and Height any more doesn't mean they should be hidden.  You could always define an ISquare interface to define a simpler set of methods for other classes that use Square.

Comment: @mbeckish Interfaces inheritance seems a good way to go. ISquare being IRectangle without getting conflicting implementations

Answer (score 1):

At first thought, I think I would declare `Rectangle`'s `Height` and `Width` as virtual and override it in the `Square` class, instead of trying to hide them :

```
class Square : Rectangle
{    
    public float Side{get;set;}

    public override float Height { get{return Side;}; set{Side =value;} }
    public override float Width {get{return Side;}; set{Side =value;} }

    public Square() : base() { }

    public Square(float side)
    {
        this.Side = side;
    }
}
```

Comment: note that changing the `Side` here doesn't actually change the base-type's width/height

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, I should have stated that I don't think inheritance is a good idea here. I just can't figure out where I would put diamond and parallelogram.

Comment: @MarcGravell Your comment kept me thinking I missed something really important here in thinking that not changing the base class values should not be a real problem, as long as I don't invoke base.Height/Width in the Square class, and as long as the Rectangle class does not refer to a specific implementation of the virtual Width and Height (namely some _width/_height). Could you provide some hints on this matter ? (or maybe I should ask a question if hints can not fit in comments)

Answer (score 1):

What is an advantage of **Square** inheritance from **Rectangle**?
Maybe you need a new class like:

```
abstract class Square<TFigure> where TFigure : Shape
{
  public float Side {set; get;}

  protected Square(TFigure stereotype)
  {
     Side = GetStereotypeSide(stereotype) 
  }

  public abstract float GetStereotypeSide(TFigure stereotype);
}
```

then your square can look like following

```
class RectangleSquare: Square<Rectangle>
{
  public RectangleSquare() : base (new Rectangle(){Height = 1, Width = 2})
  {
  }

  public override float GetStereotypeSide(Rectangle stereotype)
  {
     return stereotype.Height*stereotype.Width;
  }
}
```

in case you still need a common object for **Square** and **Shape** than you can define

```
interface IGeometry{
}
```

and then add the interface inheritance to both classes

```
    class Shape : IGeometry
  ....
```

and

```
abstract class Square<TFigure> : IGeometry where TFigure : Shape
```

Answer (score 0):

I echo @aquaraga. If you desire to hide what's public in a base class then derivation is not right. Composition is a better solution, delegating to the the other (base) class when necessary.